# What are the rules about changing your entry for the weekly featured image?

Tags: discussion, featured-photo, rules

This week I noticed that one of the entries was changed:

[this](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/2476/1)
to
[this](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/2476/2)
Is that "legal"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Don't do that.

Comment: So should a comment b made on the post?

Comment: Yeah, you should really post once and leave it. Changing it messes with the votes, as an entirely different photograph might get votes very differently. If you see something like that, post a comment and we'll address it. If it occurs early on before many votes are given, we'll usually leave it alone. Otherwise we might delete it from the contest that week.